# JavaFX canvas 2D game: Shift background vs. painting

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, 2d

I've been looking up tutorials and stuff the past couple days. I've been a programmer for many years but I have never messed with making game up until now.

I'm in the process of making just a small 2D game using Java canvas, but I'm trying to choose the correct method in painting the tile maps.

As it stands my canvas is 640x512 and it will currently paint all visible tiles per frame rate onto the viewport. To me this seems a bit over kill, but everything I have read suggests it this way.

I was just curious if there is a way to draw the entire map behind the viewport and shift so it only has to be drawn once, and then render the objects above the map every frame rate.

Any opinions would be much appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Is it that the view of the game is smaller than the game world and you want to only draw what's visible for performance reasons?

Comment: Sorry that it's a bit confusing, but yeah the view of the game is smaller than the game world, and so I'm currently drawing only what is visible for performance reasons yeah,

 but I was curious if it is possible to draw the entire region once and then shift it across the canvas. This way the only thing being rendered every frame rate is the entities and not every tile. It may not be possible.. but I don't know and I cannot find an answer.

Comment: I just notice how in games that have a zoom, you can see the entire region of the map as you zoom in and out, but not all of the entities. As soon as you move closer to an entity they come into render distance and become visible. So I'm trying to understand how this is being done. Maybe as you zoom out it increases the map render distance, and the render distances of entities is totally different? i may try looking into that.

Comment: IMO, this question is too broad to be reasonably answered on StackOverflow.  Some related information which may (or may not) help is: [View of the application javafx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15072108/view-of-the-application-javafx), [How do you load a tmx/xml file in javafx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339837/how-do-you-load-a-tmx-xml-file-in-javafx), [Writing a Tile Engine in JavaFX](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/writing-a-tile-engine-in-javafx.html) (annoying advertisements on last link).

Comment: Thank you Jewelsea, AlmasB pretty well pinpointed what I was aiming for but I am going to read into those links for more understanding. I appreciate your time. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm in the process of making just a small 2D game using Java canvas,
>   but I'm trying to choose the correct method in painting the tile maps.

There are essentially 2 ways of JavaFX rendering: scene graph (multiple nodes, auto render), or canvas (single node, manual render). If you have many objects on the screen the latter is preferred for performance reasons. Otherwise, the former, which provides a higher level approach to drawing.

> As it stands my canvas is 640x512 and it will currently paint all
>   visible tiles per frame rate onto the viewport.

It is perfectly fine to do this with JavaFX Canvas. JavaFX has a powerful rendering pipeline that figures out the best and most efficient way of rendering your scene graph. If the pixel is not in the active viewport (part that is **actually** visible on the screen), it will not be rendered. You can read about JavaFX architecture [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#JFXST788).

> I was just curious if there is a way to draw the entire map behind the
>   viewport and shift so it only has to be drawn once, and then render
>   the objects above the map every frame rate.

At lower levels JavaFX or even lower Direct3D (Windows), OpenGL (Mac/Linux) will handle this for you. Maybe not exactly in this way, but they typically do cache textures to offload memory bus. In majority of cases when attempting to optimize rendering, the steps that are taken actually slow down the process, so in a sense those steps simply get in the way of proper low level optimizations. Thus, decreasing the overall performance.

To summarize, first and foremost focus on completing the application logic and only then worry about optimizations. Even then, it is a sensitive issue and must be done with proper tools that allow you to profile and pinpoint the bottleneck in your application.

Comment: Thanks Almas. Your answer was very detailed and exactly I was trying to undertand. :)