# Resizing a 2D JavaFX game

Tags: java, optimization, javafx, 2d, game-engine

I'm currently making my first tile-based game in JavaFX, and quite early on I've run into an issue. I want to make the size of the object in the game (including the map) resize with the window, so that you won't be able to see a larger part of the game if you resize your window.

I'm using a `Scale` class which calculates the size of tiles. To make it responsible to rescaling of the window, it uses properties. The `viewport` variable is a rectangle with the width and height of the window:

```
public class Scale {        
    private static DoubleProperty widthProperty, heightProperty;
    private static DoubleBinding tileWidthProperty, tileHeightProperty;

    public static void initialize(Rectangle viewport){
        widthProperty = viewport.widthProperty();
        heightProperty = viewport.heightProperty();

        tileWidthProperty = tileHeightProperty = new DoubleBinding() {
            {
              super.bind(widthProperty, heightProperty); // initial bind
            }

            @Override
            protected double computeValue() {
              return Math.round(Math.max(widthProperty.get(), heightProperty.get())/32);
            }
        };
    }

    public static DoubleBinding x(int n){
        return tileWidthProperty.multiply(n);
    }

    public static DoubleBinding y(int n){
        return tileHeightProperty.multiply(n);
    }
}
```

All objects base their size and position on these `tileWidthProperty` and `tileHeightProperty` variables, like so:

```
Tree tree = new Tree();
tree.widthProperty.bind(Scale.x(2));
tree.heightProperty.bind(Scale.y(3));
tree.xProperty.bind(Scale.x(12));
tree.yProperty.bind(Scale.x(2));
```

All tiles are scaled and positioned in the same way.

When first starting the game, there is little to no lag. However, when the window is resized and all the properties change, the client freezes. My question is: Is there any way to optimize this resizing? Should I do it in a different way than I am with these properties? If so, what would be most efficient?

Comment: I know nothing about JavaFX, but when I was trying somthing similar with Java, I used double buffering. I would render to a BufferedImage first, then scale that to fit the viewport, if I remember correctly. Hope this helps or is at least a pointer for further research.

Comment: @domdom JavaFX uses a pulse-based rendering mechanism: double buffering doesn't make any difference here.

Comment: Does the application completely freeze (i.e. hang?). Or does it just get very slow? I suspect something else is wrong in your logic somewhere: e.g. your `viewport` is changing size when the properties in `Scale` change, which would cause infinite recursion.

Comment: @James_D the application completely freezes for about half a minute, then runs fine again. The size of `viewport` is linked to the size of the `primaryStage` - that shouldn't cause infinite recursion, right?

Comment: If what you describe is what you're doing, then no, that shouldn't cause an issue. But neither should the code you posted.

Comment: @James_D when I resize the window, thousands of tiles and other objects are scaled and repositioned though. Would there be any way to scale the parent that contains all the other nodes on the window resize? I can't really think of anyother way to do this efficiently

Comment: Hmm. Any way you can create a [MCVE] that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @James_D after making an mcv example I realized that the lag was not just caused by the use of properties (showing and resizing 2,500,000 tiles barely caused any lag). I'll have to benchmark my code to find out where the problem lies. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: So, 2 and a half million tiles and each tile is a node?  That seems to be too many nodes to add to the scene graph, perhaps you should consider using a [tile engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20339837/how-do-you-load-a-tmx-xml-file-in-javafx).

Comment: @jewelsea yeah, I realize that in an actual game, 2.5 million tiles would be a little too much. I only used that many tiles in a small test program I wrote to check if the lag was due to using properties - turns out it wasn't, as 2.5m tiles barely caused any lag. In the actual program, I'm showing a maximum of 1024 tiles on the screen at any moment

Comment: Do you want to achieve something like this?  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GdUSoCoz2_o